# How to compute Bochner laplacian $\Delta=\nabla^*\nabla=\sum \nabla_{e_i}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I'm struggling with proving that [Bochner laplacian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operators_in_differential_geometry#Bochner_Laplacian) can be described by the following formula similar to the standard laplacian formula from calculus: $$\Delta = \sum_i \nabla_i^2,$$ where $\nabla_i = \nabla_{e_i}$ for some local orthonormal basis $e_i$ and $\nabla$ is a connection satisfying any reasonable conditions (Levi-Civita on $TM$, the induced connections on $\Omega^k(M)$).

We live on a compact $C^\infty$ Riemannian manifold without boundary and the laplace operator is defined as $\nabla^*\nabla$, where $\nabla$ is viewed as a map $\Gamma(E)\to \Gamma(T^*M \otimes E)$ between spaces with scalar product and thus the adjoint operator $\nabla^*\!\!:\Gamma(T^*M \otimes E) \to \Gamma(E)$ is well defined*.

I'm new to Levi-Civita, so please be understanding if the solution is trivial...

*Actually the spaces here are neither finite dimensional nor Hilbert, so it is not clear if the adjoint operator exists... The explanation will be highly appreciated, but it can be assumed that $\nabla^*$ exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This calculation is done in full detail (without the assumption that the basis is orthonormal) in example $10.1.32$ of Liviu Nicolaescu's wonderful book *Lectures on the Geometry of Manifolds* which is freely available as a pdf from [his website](http://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/vita.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I must admit that I expected the calculation to be more straightforward :(

Comment: It is more straightforward if the basis is orthonomal. In that case $g^{ij} = \delta^{ij}$ so things simplify quite a bit.

Comment: Also see page 210 of Petersen.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Liviu Nicolaescu's book is indeed very good. Do you know what book of Petersen mdg was talking about? He was last seen more than three years ago, otherwise I would have asked him.

Comment: @Filippo: I believe it is *Riemannian Geometry* by Peter Petersen.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Thank you for the reply. I have access to his book from 2016, but I didn't find a treatment of Bochner Laplacians. The Lichnerowicz Laplacian introduced on page 344 looks similar, but I didn't find a computation in coordinates.

Comment: @Filippo: I think mdg was referring to the second edition, while you have the third. I've had a brief look at the third edition, and I believe Petersen chose not to include the general result from the second edition, but rather focus on some specific cases in the subsections of section 9.4.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Thank you very much for your time :) I was able to download the second edition and I think you are right: On page $210$ Petersen shows that $$\nabla^*=-\mathrm{tr}(\nabla^2)$$and this seems to be equivalent to the desired result, since$$\mathrm{tr}(\nabla^2)=\sum_{i=1}^n\nabla_{e_i}\nabla_{e_i}-\nabla_{\nabla_{e_i}e_i}$$if $e$ is an orthonormal frame (see page $209$ and $29$).

Comment: Of course I meant $\nabla^*\nabla=-\mathrm{tr}(\nabla^2)$...